# Upper bound for real part of Riemann Zeta function zeros

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I have been reading about Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$ and have been thinking about it for some time. I did some calculations, and reached a conclusion where $\Re(\rho) \le \log_2(3) - 1$ as $\Im(\rho) \to \infty$ where $\rho$'s are the roots of Riemann Zeta function in the critical strip. Anyways, I know its not the place to discuss claimed proofs and similar stuff, but just to give a background of where I am coming from. So straight to the question.

> Is there any similar result regarding upper
>   bound ($< 1$) for the real part of the zeros zeta
>   function as their imaginary
>   parts tend to infinity?

Thanks

Comment: All results on zero-free regions have a strip with width tending to 0 as the imaginary part increases.

Comment: All known results on zero free regions are of the form $\zeta(\sigma+it) \neq 0$ when $\sigma > 1 - f(t)$, for some function $f$ with `$\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) =0$`. A bound of the form you describe would be major progress. 

Comment: Honestly, you almostly certainly have an error. Your past questions have involved a number of elementary errors about analytic number theory and you are working on a problem which is notorious for drawing mathematicians into false proofs. In addition, if you are who I think you are, than 3 of your 6 papers on the arXiv have been withdrawn. (I am glad that you do withdraw errors!) Based on the little I know about you, you really need to find an advisor or mentor who can teach you how to do careful work in analytic number theory. 

Comment: If the proof is incorrect, what is the first equation in the paper that is incorrect?

Comment: You could look for yourself.  I did, and the limit $\tau \to \infty$ at the beginning of Section 4 looks pretty dubious.

Comment: (5) is correct, hence (6) is wrong.

Comment: you may contact Prof.Bhaskar Bagchi of ISI,Bangalore.He was arguably the most interested person in India in RH.or you may contact me at bmat1013@isibang.ac.in. I am from ISI,Bangalore.

Comment: Prof.B.Bagchi spent 20 yrs trying to prove RH.

Comment: @user1952009 No, I cannot be your mentor, both because I am spending enough time on my actual graduate and undergraduate students, and because I am not an analytic number theorist.

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry, I guess I was being overliteral and dumb. No offense taken and I hope none given. Anyways, I looked at the question briefly and didn't think of anything to say.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer ok tks, sry for being annoying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no known non-trivial (less than 1) bound for real parts of Zeta zeros (I guess, it is even called "weak Riemann conjecture" to find such a bound). So, your result is very-very interesting, maybe the most interesting result in mathematics for many years.

Comment: I was searching for papers having zero free regions... and most of them gave results like $\Re(\rho) > 1 - \beta$. Are you sure there are  no such results? (I'll wait before accepting your answer)

Comment: EDIT: by "no such results" I mean no results with $\Re(\rho) < c < 1$. Sorry for the typo

Comment: I think after Speyer's comments I am ready to accept you answer... Thanks Fedor and Speyer !!!

Comment: Here's my paper if anyone is actually interested :DDD                       https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=1222Q9gXqrNFZdzMhheDZzeQ5EqyG3loEidp_iorGpDS9kjHJ8hLAsHH7BU8z&hl=en&pli=1

Comment: If I recall correctly, even proving things like a zero free sliver near Re = 1 would have major ramifications in making effective many of the cryptographic applications of RH (or really GRH).

Comment: the latest on this is https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.04644 - using a recent disproval of Connes' embedding conjecture