# Do we know an upper bound for the number of possible real parts of the non trivial zeroes of $\zeta$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $n_{\zeta}$ denote the number of possible real parts for the non trivial zeroes of the Riemann Zeta function. RH is equivalent to $n_{\zeta}=1$, and the symmetry arising from the functional equation implies that $n_{\zeta}$ is odd.

My question is thus: do we know an upper bound for $n_{\zeta}$? Are we at least sure it is finite?

Comment: I don't think a supposed uncountability would be compatible with the fact that at least 41% of these zeroes are on the critical line.

Comment: More simply, the set of zeros is discrete, hence countable. But I don't think it is known that the set of real parts has an upper bound which is $<1$.

Comment: it is not known if $\zeta(s)$ has a sequence of zeros whose real part converge to $1^-$. If it does, then the number of different real parts of the non-trivial zeros between $1-\epsilon$ and $1$ has to be $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for example mentioned as open in [a 2010 answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/41120) by Fedor Petrov to basically a duplicate question.

It might be worth noting that nothing new has been proven in these last 6 years, or it would have been big news.